# How to find if a perversely constructed object is empty in PHP

Tags: php, object

I'm working with an object fed back from a class. For some reason, the class spits out an object with numbered properties (0, 1, 2, etc.). I need to check if the object is empty. The standard trick, `empty(get_object_vars($obj))`, won't work, because `get_object_vars` returns an empty array even when the object has (numbered) properties.

For reference, the object I'm working with is the one returned by the legislatorsZipCode method of the PHP interface for Sunlight's API. You can see a `print_r` of a sample response [here](http://emmense.com/sunlight-labs-php-library/sunlightlegislator-class/sunlightlegislatorlegislatorzipcode/).

Comment: This is why you don't cast a numerically indexed array to an object.  Though you could cast the object back to an array...

Comment: Note that casting to an array would give you string keys `$foo["0"]` instead of `$foo[0]`.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer, I see what you are getting at. `$foo = (array) $obj;` is different from `$foo->{0} = 'bar';`, which is quite strange. I've deleted my answer for now since I don't know of any way other than to cast it to an array.

Comment: @konforce: SO interface is bugging out at the moment so I gave up trying to come up and explain a proof.  But yeah, it's all about the _type_ of the key/property name that is in question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the code, the author made the mistake of casting a numerically indexed array to an object.  This makes getting object properties by name impossible, though you should still be able to `foreach` over it.  You can also simply cast it back to an array: `$results = (array) $obj;`.  Then, `count` the array.

Comment: +1. I think casting it to an explicit array is the best approach. I would probably simply overwrite the original object `$obj = (array) $obj` and work with it as the powers have intended.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
if (current($obj) === false)
  echo "is empty\n";
```

It probably is doing an implicit cast to an array.